# Xades-BES validation as checksum

Tags: java, xades4j

I am trying to verify a document signed by xades4j but I'm not interested in a certificate validation. The only thing I need to know is that the document has been signed correctly and nothing has been changed since the signing.

I've tried a few different approaches but each one uses PKIXCertificateValidationProvider which requires parameters I'm not interested in like trusted certs. The same is used also in unittests in xades4j sources. I even tried to implement CertificateValidationProvider myself but certificates are needed later on by other classes like ValidationData.

Do you have any suggestion how to achieve this with xades4j? Or maybe some other library better documented I could use for validation purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach for that scenario is implementing a CertificateValidationProvider. The validation data returned by the `validate` method should at least return a list with the signing certificate.

A possible implementation of `validate` for your scenario would be to match the *certSelector* against the supplied certificates and return a list with the first certificate that matches. This would only work if the signature contains the certificate...

Comment: So does it mean I will have to parse xml myself by hand and get certificate first? Do you know in which place the xml validation takes place? The validation if the message has not been changed.